# How to upload an image on UPLOADS.IM from Local Drive

Tags: php, json, api, url

As i can see below: http://uploads.im/apidocs

That documentation explain how the API give features to upload a files from computer using POST or GET method

Example: http://uploads.im/api?upload=http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo66.png

Is anybody know how to upload an image from local drive to that URL using some PHP Script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload Your image by CURL:

```
curl --form "fileupload=@YOUR_IMAGE.jpg" http://uploads.im/api?upload
```

OR like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://uploads.im/api?upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="SEND FILE">
</form>
```

Comment: Oh yeah that's a great example, why such a easy way like that did not cross in my mind (-_-")
Thanks dude

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to uplaod an image to uploads.im but I could not manage to upload an image (I kept getting empty responses).

I switched to [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com) and was able to upload an image with the following ruby script:

```
require 'json'

user_slug = 'your-identifier'
url = "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/#{user_slug}/image/upload"
file = '~/Desktop/upload.png'
api_key = 'SECRET'

# https://cloudinary.com/console/settings/upload#upload_presets
preset = 'uploads'

result =   `curl -F "upload_preset=#{preset}" -F "api_key=#{api_key}" -F "file=@#{file}" #{url}`

url = JSON.parse(result)['url']
`open #{url}`
```

While this is a ruby script you could easily upload an image via "naked" `curl`. Please note the `@`-prefix for the file path:

```
curl -F "upload_preset={preset}" -F "api_key={your_api_key}" -F "file=@{file_path} https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/{your_account_slug}/image/upload"
```